# Equivalent to Mongoose `.populate` for ObjectIds in Array that maintains array order

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

What’s the MongoDB aggregation equivalent to Mongoose’s `.populate` on arrays? Specifically, I’m wondering if there’s anything that will a) perform the functionality of `$lookup` but b) still keep array order with the returned objects.

I.e., looking up the items in `[ ObjectId(b), ObjectId(a), ObjectId(c) ]` should return the array in the same order `[ ItemB, ItemA, ItemC ]`, and **not** `[ItemA, ItemB, ItemC]` or any other permutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a regular `$lookup` and then order the results:

```
db.colA.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
    from: "colB",
    localField: "data",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "newData"
  }},
  {$set: {
    newData: "$$REMOVE",
    data: {
      $map: {
        input: "$data",
        in: {$arrayElemAt: ["$newData", {$indexOfArray: ["$newData._id", "$$this"]}]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f_zBborywb3)